# Batch file to execute another batch file based on the multiple input

Tags: batch-file

My requirement is to execute a batch file by providing the argument. These argument will be passed one by one to the first batch script. For this I have written the below code. Please help in modifying the issue.

Code:

```
SET TEST_CASE=testcase1,testCase2,testCase3
SET OS_HOME=C:\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
SET OS_REPO=C:\###############
echo +++ Message : Oracle Open Script installation path, PATH=%OS_HOME%
echo +++ Message : Oracle Open script checked out at location, PATH=%OS_REPO%
for /F "delims=," %%f in ("%TEST_CASE%") do (
    echo +++ Message : Executing the test case :%%f
    %OS_HOME%\runScript.bat %OS_REPO%\%%f\%%f\%%f.jwg
    pause
)
```

Please help, it is not executing the batch file as the value of `%%f` in `%OS_REPO%\%%f\%%f\%%f.jwg` is showing empty.

Comment: this batch file is only executing for the first parameter

Comment: Add `call` in front of `%OS_HOME%\runScript.bat`.

Comment: use a plain `for`: `for %%f in (%Test_Case%) do (`. See `for /?` for details. And use `call` to call a secondary batchfile (as Klitos already mentioned)

Comment: Variable `%SCRIPT_REPO%` is not defined; did you mean `%OS_REPO%`?

Comment: @aschipfl, yes  its just typo while writing code over here

Comment: Call part is triggering the batch file to execute but only for the first argument not for the second iteration in second argument